# Add Quasar Tooltip to a q-list that is built with code

Tags: javascript, html, quasar

I'm trying to add a tooltip to a `q-list` that is build via code:

```
      <q-list bordered>
    <q-item v-for="item in iCite_Data" :key="item.id"   v-ripple>
      <q-item-section>       
      <q-item-label > 
             {{ item.label }}               
       </q-item-label> 
    </q-item-section>
    <q-item-section side> 
       <q-item-label>{{ item.value }}</q-item-label>         
    </q-item-section>
  </q-item>
```

I have tried putting as a test:

```
  <q-tooltip content-class="bg-indigo" :offset="[10, 10]">
     {{ item.tooltip}}
    </q-tooltip>
```

When I add a tooltip to a hard coded q-item it works.

https://codepen.io/morgenweck/pen/VwprbrY?editors=1010

but if I try to add to a `q-item` built from code it does not.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Here is a basic Quasar codepen from code.

https://codepen.io/morgenweck/pen/VwpMNOO

Comment: The correct location of `<q-tooltip>` in your case is as a child of `<q-item>`, not wrapping anything except the tooltip text. I don't have a Quasar 1 testbed handy, but in my Quasar 2 context, that structure works fine. By default, Quasar tooltips are appended to `<body>` while rendered, so there might be some broader HTML or CSS issue at work. Can you add a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Added to the original question.  Each item has a seperate tooltip

Comment: Thanks! In the second pen you linked, the tooltips are appearing for me in the first and third columns where they're defined. (There doesn't appear to be any `<q-tooltip>` in the second column.) Are you not getting tooltips on hover in that pen? What browser/version are you using?

Comment: I went back and make them into {{ contact.tooltip }} and that worked.  I was using static text as my sample and apparently static does not work.. All good now-- THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must replace the static text `Some text as content of Tooltip` with interpolation `{{ contact.tooltip }}` - and you will see your dynamic tooltips.

Comment: I would never have thought that static text would not work--Thanks for the help

Comment: Static text works just fine - but the same text will be used for all tooltips and you do not want that, you want each QItem to have its own text for the tooltip and this is why you need the interpolation.